How can I implement Google, Facebook, Microsoft OAuth authentication with Delphi?
I've been trying to implement on my Delphi multiplatform apps a social login approach, but had no success. I understood the process, but when I tried to add Google Oauth authentication, I faced the issue: TWebBrowser. I could do almost everything with REST components (RestClient, RestRequest, etc.) but when I have to direct the user to Google's page to allow the process and get the code to use it with Firebase Authentication, I've got a message on the browser saying that TWebBrowser doesn't have support for it. I searched, but found nothing about it.
My question is basically, how can I show the Google page to let the user  proceed to social login since TWebBrowser is not supported by Google? It shows it's not supported because it's an embeddedbrowser.

Google is picky and often dissallows some authorization flows with short notice after security issues are found. Make sure you read and follow the latest docs, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
